# Adding output as pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script that will check if a port is open from the source system to a target hostname, getting the information for `host` and `port` variables from an excel file.

```
input_file = "somefile.xlsx"

def process_excel(input_file):
    # Read the input Excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(input_file, usecols='C,F')
    df = df.drop_duplicates()

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # Grab info from rows
        host = row["Backend"]
        port = row["Port"]
        check_socket(host, port)


def check_socket(host, port):
    console = Console(color_system="windows") # this is for color in console output
    with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as sock:  # Checks if the hostname:port is open from the source system
        try:
            if sock.connect_ex((host, port)) == 0:
                console.print(f"{host}:{port}   [green]Open")
            else:
                console.print(f"{host}:{port}  [red]Closed")
        except Exception as e:
            console.print(f"{host}:{port} - [dark_orange3]Not Found[/dark_orange3] -", f"[bright_red]{e}")
```

This prints exactly what I want to the console, but I'd also like it to write the output back to a new excel file with columns "Host", "Port", "Status". How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is probably the simplest way of achieving what you're after

I would approach the problem in this manner:

```py
def process_excel(input_file: str, out_file: str) -> None:
    # Read the input Excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(input_file, usecols='C,F')
    df = df.drop_duplicates()

    df["Status"] = df.apply(lambda r: check_socket(r["Backend"], r["Port"]), axis="columns")

    df.to_excel(out_file)
```

and update your `check_socket` function to return the value you want shown in the Status column. Then use the dataframe method to [write your output back to an Excel file](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: I updated the code with your suggested line. Really nice one line solution, thank you. However I'm unsure on how to accomplish your last suggestion of the dataframe method to write the returned status to the excel file. 

I added the lines `status = "open"` and `return status`, but now I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer to include information on how to write a dataframe to Excel